# how puppeteer handles scrolling in headless mode

Tags: jasmine, e2e-testing, headless, headless-browser, puppeteer

so i have this e2e test environment(test framework is jasmine)
which is being powered by puppeteer(**headless mode**.)
the mechanism works in a way which puppeteer triggers the test's url in a page , and wait's for jasmine to end it's evaluation.
everything works great **beside** **tests which involves scrolling to a certain area in the viewport**. 
if i change headless to false , the tests run's great.
so, anyone knows if puppeteer knows how to deal with scrolling in headless?
thanks ! (if anyone has a different hint why things are not working feel free to share)

Comment: A thought: Are you specifying the viewport size in the tests? I would not think so, but *perhaps* the viewport size is different in headless mode.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for you, but you can see what's going on with the browser (visually) with this debugger: https://chrome.browserless.io/. That might give some insight into _what's_ happening so you can adjust or try a different method for scrolling.